# How can I mock a method that should accept an array?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, shopware

I am new to testing with PHPUnit, and what I am trying to do is test a method called `returnOnLogin()` that accepts a parameter `Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args` and returns `true`.

Here's the method I want to test:

```
public function returnOnLogin(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
{
    $controller = $args->get('subject');
    $view = $controller->View();

    $controller->redirect([
        'controller' => 'verification'
    ]);

    // $view->addTemplateDir(
    // __DIR__ . '/Views'
    // );

    return true;
}
```

Here's my test:

```
class MyFirstTestPluginTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testReturnOnLogin()
    {
        $my_plugin = new MyFirstTestPlugin(true);
        $expected = true;

       //I tried following but it did not work
       $this->assertEquals($expected, $my_plugin->returnOnLogin(//here is the problem it requires this array that I dont know));
   }
```

}

Comment: maybe start from here: https://phpunit.de/documentation.html ? and provide more info about your case. As I assume that `returnOnLogin` is defined in a class.

Comment: You just need to run the `returnOnLogin` method, and call `assertTrue` on the result. Which bit are you having trouble with?

Comment: yes the returnOnLogin is inside the MyFirstTestPlugin class. I will take a look at that thank you. I am having trouble with passing the parameter. I edited my code take a look at the last line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your controller class is `Controller`, and assuming that we don't care that `view()` is invoked in `$controller`, this should cover what you are looking for:

```
class MyFirstTestPluginTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testReturnOnLogin()
    {
        /**
         * create a test double for the controller (adjust to your controller class)
         */
        $controller = $this->createMock(Controller::class);

        /**
         * expect that a method redirect() is called with specific arguments
         */
        $controller
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('redirect')
            ->with($this->identicalTo([
                'controller' => 'verification'
            ]));

        /**
         * create a test double for the arguments passed to returnLogin()
         */
        $args = $this->createMock(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs::class);

        /** 
         * expect that a method subject() is invoked and return the controller from it
         */
        $args
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('subject')
            ->willReturn($controller);

        $plugin = new MyFirstTestPlugin(true);

        $this->assertTrue($plugin->returnOnLogin($args));
    }
}
```

### What does this test do?

#### Arrange

This test first *arranges* test doubles for use with the system under test (your plugin).

The first test double is your controller, we set it up in such a way that we expect that a method `redirect()` is invoked once with an argument that is identical to the specified array.

The second test double is the argument, we set it up in such a way that we expect that a method 'subject()` is invoked one, and will return the controller.

Then, we set up the system under test, simply by creating an instance of `MyFirstTestPlugin`, passing `true` to the constructor.

Unfortunately, you haven't shared the constructor with us, we have no idea what the argument `true` stands for. If it affects the behaviour of `returnLogin()`, then we clearly need to add more tests to assert the behaviour when the argument takes different values.

#### Act

Then this test invokes the method `returnLogin()` on the system under test, and passes in one of the test doubles.

#### Assert

Eventually, this test asserts that the method `returnLogin()` returns `true`.

**Note** Take a look at

- http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrangeActAssert
- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Comment: Glad I could help, maybe you want to take a look at some of the books by Chris Hartjes, they helped me getting started with testing a while ago.